# Forcing Zone/Digest on a pipe with static falsy

Tags: angular, ngfor, zone.js

In my angular 4 template I have a simple pipe with a boolean I toggle to check if a user has been created

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | existingUser : existingUserToggleFlag">
```

above my data I have my ng-repeat counts like this :

```
<span> Total Users: {{users.length}}
<span> Existing : {(users | existingUser : true)?.length} </span>
<span> NON-Existing : {(users | existingUser : false)?.length} </span>
```

As you can see I pass in pipe's argument as a static falsy from the template. The template does not update though, it only update when I use the existingUserToggleFlag. I can get the length of those no problem:

```
<span> Existing : {(users | existingUser : existingUserToggleFlag)?.length} </span>
```

I'm assuming its the digest not kicking off, as I console log and it appears (first glance via console.log) that my pipe does not get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Set `users` and the pipe in parentheses as shown in the [FlyingHeroesPipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pipes-and-change-detection) sample.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of (users | existingUser : existingUserToggleFlag)">
```

The interpolation in your `span` elements needs to be corrected to `{{ .. }}`

```
<span> Existing : {{(users | existingUser : true)?.length}} </span>
<span> NON-Existing : {{(users | existingUser : false)?.length}} </span
```

If this did not work, post your Pipe implementation.